# v5 how to replicate rsi behaviour with series as length

Tags: pine-script

In pinescript `v4` it was possible to pass a series as `length` argument.
As documentation states:

```
If x is a series and y is a series then x and y are considered to be 2 calculated MAs for upward and downward changes.
```

Now with `v5` it's not possible anymore. You can only pass a simple integer.
Considering it is not possible to cast a series into a simple integer, how do I achieve the previous behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to achieve the same behavior that happens when you pass series length to `rsi()` in v4, you can use a formula. The formula is specified in the [Pine User Manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_5.html#removed-an-rsi-overload):

```
100.0 - (100.0 / (1.0 + arg1 / arg2))
```

Comment: Didn't see the section related to the rsi. Thanks for pointing it out!